A *.exe file created with pyinstaller aborts when creating a *.xml file
I have a Python project in which, among other things, I create a SEPA DEBIT *.xml file. When executing the program point in PyCharm everything works very well.
After I created an *.exe with Pyinstaller, an error occurred when creating the *.xml file and the program aborted. The error message is displayed in the image. For whatever reason, Pyinstaller does not create the path you are looking for, even though the xmlschema folder is located in the project at /.venv/Lip/site.packages.
I've tried a lot of things, unfortunately so far without success.
Attached is my code for creating the *.xml file.

`def create_sepa_xml(data_ra, filename, data_own_bank):
b = ""
if data_own_bank[0][9] == 1:
    b = "True"
elif data_own_bank[0][9] == 0:
    b = "False"

client = {
    "name": data_own_bank[0][0],
    "IBAN": data_own_bank[0][1],
    "BIC": data_own_bank[0][2],
    "batch": b,
    "creditor_id": data_own_bank[0][11],
    "currency": "EUR",
}
sepa = SepaDD(client, schema="pain.008.002.02")

typ = ["FRST", "RCUR", "OOFF"]
index = int(data_own_bank[0][8])
tage_einzugsfrist = data_own_bank[0][7]

for e in data_ra:
    datu = convert_mandate_date(e[17])
    amount = round(e[23], 2)
    amount2 = int(amount * 100)
    redat = convert_redat(e[3])
    renr = e[2]
    kunr = e[4]
    text = "ReNr:" + str(renr) + " KuNr:" + str(kunr) + " ReDat:" + redat
    debtor = {
        "name": e[12],
        "IBAN": e[15],
        "BIC": e[14],
        "amount": amount2,
        "type": typ[index],  # FRST, RCUR, OOFF, FNAL
        "collection_date": date.today() + timedelta(days=int(tage_einzugsfrist)),  # int(coll_date)),
        "mandate_id": e[16],
        "mandate_date": date(datu.year, datu.month, datu.day),  # date(2022, 9, 2),
        "description": text,
    }
    sepa.add_payment(debtor)

pain_message = sepa.export()
example = parseString(pain_message).toprettyxml()

with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(example)
msgbox.callMessagebox_ok("*.XML Datei erstellt.", "erledigt", )`


if you're using relative paths, have you checked where the current directory is? it's a common mistake to assume what current directory is set. When using pyinstaller or such, main __file__ attribute doesn't work you have to use sys.executable to locate the exec/main script dir

Why doesn't pyinstaller create a folder like "xmlschema" in my "dist/main/_internal" folder?
What do you mean by "you have to use sys.executable to locate the exec/main script dir". Can you give me an example?

Sorry for incorrect wording. Why doesn't pyinstaller create NO folder like "xmlschema" in my "dist/main/_internal" folder? What do you mean by "you have to use sys.executable to locate the exec/main script dir". Can you give me an example?
